# Solving simultaneous equations using a determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Upon revisiting the lecture notes from the first year undergraduate mathematics course I took, I found the following problem

> Factorise the determinant $$\text{det}\begin{pmatrix}z & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & z & 3 \\ 1 & 1 & z+1 \end{pmatrix}$$ and hence solve the simultaneous equations $$ zx + y = 2, \ \ \  x + zy = 3, \ \ \ x + y = z+1.$$

The determinant is $(z-1)(z^2+2z-4)$, but how does this help to solve the simultaneous equations?

One way to solve the equations is by substituting $y = z + 1 - x$ into the first two equations, yielding $$z(x+1) = x + 1 $$ and $$x + z(z + 1 - x) = 3. $$ Then if $x \neq -1$ we get $z = 1$, implying that $x + 2 - x = 3$, a contradiction. Hence, $x = -1$.

Substituting this into the three simultaneous equations we get $zy = 4$ and $y = z + 2$. Hence $z \neq 0$, and so $\frac{4}{z} = z + 2$, yielding $z^2 + 2z - 4 = 0$ (one of the factors of the determinant!). Solving this quadratic equation for $z$ and using the fact that $y = z+2$ we obtain $z = -1 \pm \sqrt{5}$ and $y = 1 \pm \sqrt{5}$.

I'm not seeing the connection to the determinant in the statement of the problem. How does factoring the determinant lead to a solution of the simultaneous equations?

Comment: Where did you learn this method, what are your unknowns?

Comment: @ZAhmed the context of the problem is a first course in mathematics at the undergraduate level in which determinants have just been introduced. When you say "unknowns" are you referring to the simultaneous equations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y=z+1-x$. Then the two remaining equations are
\begin{align*}
f(x,z) & =xz - x + z - 1=0,\cr
g(x,z) & =- xz + x + z^2 + z - 3=0.
\end{align*}
Now the resultant of $f$ and $g$ with respect to $x$ is given by
$$
{\rm res}(f,g,x)=z^3 + z^2 - 6z + 4=(z-1)(z^2+2z-4),
$$
which is exactly the determinant in question. Of course, the resultant gives the common roots of the two polynomials, i.e., it resolves the equations.

The result is not surprising, since we know that the resultant of two polynomials can be computed by the determinant of the Sylvester matrix, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant).